# Why would a terminal server be kicking users off after about 5 minutes?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I have a terminal server that was restored from an old 1U server to an IBM HS20 Blade running ESXi.

The restore was using shadow protect hardware independent restore.  All appeared to be functioning well but we're finding that users are being periodically kicked off after around 5 minutes or so.
 The interesting thing is it doesn't appear to be a simple disconnect but the whole session has gone like it was logged out.

There is nothing significant in the event log, and certainly nothing from terminal services that is logged.  I've also checked the client computers and from the client computers logged into our other terminal server and there wasn't any issues there.  It doesn't appear to be network related.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I think we've isolated the issue.
We have about 100 clients running off a wireless network.  The network unfortunately has double/triple NAT's going on.  We removed that for this customer, gave them a public IP and the RDP dropping went away.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Session settings under tscc.msc.

Start > Run > tscc.msc

Right click on RDP-Tcp and go to Properties > Session Tab

Comment: Checked that.  All looks normal, nothing changed since before the shadow protect restore and it was operating fine before that.  Beginning to think it's a network level issue but not very sure

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something simple if your not sure if its a fault in software/hardware or a configuration error.

Basicly time it. 
If your sessions get disconnected after 5min every time, its most likely a configuration thing.
If the time it takes for a disconnect changes every time i could be a faulty server or at network level

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to reactivate it in terminal services licencing?